# Netbeans (ant) can't profile

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, profiling

Following the instructions [here](https://profiler.netbeans.org/docs/help/5.5/antTasksForProfiling.html) I was unable to get NetBeans to profile a simple (template) applications. 
In NetBeans I'm selecting the Profile menu's "Profile Project (xxx)" menu item (which switches to the Telemetry view). In that view I click the "Profile" button… and the program launches… I get log output to the output view (in NetBeans)… and that's it. No telemetry updates or anything.

Follow up: Following the instructions [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/getting-started-with-netbeans-profiler-81): I was able to get the anagram sample project to profile (YAY!) however I still can’t get my existing project to profile. Everything builds and launches but the telemetry data is not updated.
Someone suggested I add this line to my build.xml file (for the nb-profiler target):

```
<fail unless="profiler.info.jvmargs.agent">Must set profiler agent JVM arguments in profiler.info.jvmargs.agent</fail>
```

Sure enough, now when I run the profiler NetBeans logs the “Must set profiler agent JVM…” message. So… how do I do that? (Google’s not helping) TIA!

Here's the current build.xml target:

`<target name="profile-nb" depends="runtime-library-selection" description="build and run app with NetBeans profiling">
        <fail unless="netbeans.home">This target can only run inside the NetBeans IDE.</fail>
        <startprofiler/>
        <nbprofiledirect>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${jartarget}/app.jar"/>
                <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
            </classpath>
        </nbprofiledirect>
        <!-- commenting out this next line prevents the "Must set profiler agent JVM arguments..." message -->
        <!-- <fail unless="profiler.info.jvmargs.agent">Must set profiler agent JVM arguments in profiler.info.jvmargs.agent</fail> -->
        <java classname="${application.classname}" dir="${basedir}" fork="yes" resultproperty="application.returncode">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
            <sysproperty key="java.security.policy" value="${libdir}/security.policy"/>
            <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path=".:${arch.lib.path}:${libdir}"/>
            <sysproperty key="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            <!-- commenting out this next line prevents the "can't find main class..." message -->
            <!-- <jvmarg value="${profiler.info.jvmargs.agent}"/> -->
            <jvmarg line="${profiler.info.jvmargs}"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xms256m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx640m"/>
            <jvmarg line="${jvm.args}"/>
            <arg value="${antargline}"/>
        </java>
    </target>`

Note: as-is it will launch the app and put up a "Progress..." dialog: "Connecting to the target VM..." (which stays open until I quit the app).

Comment: Are you invoking this script from the program, or are you running Ant directly from the command line? It looks like that property isn't getting set. At the bottom of the page you linked to, it explains that the `profiler.info.*` properties are set by the Netbeans profiler program itself.

Comment: Both. In NetBeans I'm selecting the Profile menu's "Profile Project (xxx)" menu item (which switches to the Telemetry view). In that view I click the "Profile" button… and the program launches… I get log output to the output view (in NetBeans)… and that's it. No telemetry updates or anything. Running it from the command line gave me the above error (which makes since now after reading your comment.); I guess I should change my question to "Why isn't NetBeans profiling my app?". Thx. for the reply.